# active docker realms in nexus3 api

Tags: api, rest, curl, nexus3

How can i active DockerToken realms in nexus 3.38? I use this URL but not work and docker realms is not activated.

```
curl -XPUT  -H "accept: application/json" -u admin:pass  -d '{"id" : "DockerToken"}'   http://192.168.254.10:8081/service/rest/v1/security/realms/active
```

Or reamls.json

```
[
  "id": "DockerToken"
]
```

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -u admin:pass  -d @realms.json   http://192.168.254.10:8081/service/rest/v1/security/realms/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think should help this request:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin:pass  --data-raw '["NexusAuthenticatingRealm", "NexusAuthorizingRealm", "DockerToken"]' http://192.168.254.10:8081/service/rest/v1/security/realms/active
```